# How to unload a sketch

Tags: arduino-ide, sketch

I've loaded a sketch onto Arduino using the Ardunio IDE and it works but when I press the reset button I realize it doesn't remove the program. Is there a way to unload the program? Why? Because when I take it apart to put it away I don't know if having that program turning pins on or off and having nothing connected to it would break anything.

Comment: how can a device turn pins on and off when there is no power to run the device?

Comment: @jsotola right correct. i'm looking at it as if i'm going through examples for training purposes. for the case where, if i disconnect everything and put it away (but the program is not removed) then later i plug it back in where i don't have anything else connected to it then i was concerned what would have happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frist: The Arduino cannot break when nothing is connected to it, doesn't matter what the code does.

If you want to remove the current code from the Arduino, you have to overwrite it with an empty sketch (one with only `setup()` and `loop()`, both empty). So upload an empty sketch.

The reset button is not meant for erasing the code. It is meant to return the Arduino in a definited starting state (not erasing program space or EEPROM) and executing the program on the Arduino (including the bootloader) from its start.

Comment: OK Thank you. So pressing reset cuts the power, clears the memory and runs the setup and then loop function again.

Comment: It doesn't cut the power. The reset is a hardware function of the microcontroller on the Arduino. The controller will then start program executing from programm address zero. So first the bootloader gets executed (which enables to you program via USB/Serial), then your program starts, which also includes building the stack in memory for your variables. The memory is not actually erased (as in overwritten with zeros or ones), but your program implicitly will initialize the used memory with the defined values (the compiler creates such machine code from your C++ code). Then setup and co runs

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove a program by resetting the Arduino. If you want to be sure that it can't activate any pins in your next experiment, then just before you finish with it, upload a new program that does nothing, such as the Basics | Bare Minimum example program. It will effectively replace the previous program.

At power-up, all of your pins[*] get configured as inputs during power-up. With the Bare Minimum program, nothing will change those pins, until you start writing & uploading new code that modifies them.

[*] Note that the bootloader will re-configure pin-1, the serial transmitter pin, as an output.